Chemistry of lemon drop candies
I made lemon drop candies using this recipe. Here's a TL;DR:


Mix 1 cup sugar, 1/2 cup water, 1/2 teaspoon cream of tartar (inhibits crystalization), cook to 300 °F.
Pour out the candy and fold in 1/2 teaspoon lemon extract and 2 teaspoons citric acid.
Once the candy is cool enough, roll, cut, and coat with powdered sugar.


My question is, what parts of this recipe can I modify without changing the chemistry? Specifically:

I assume from this answer that adding the citric acid initially (before cooking the sugar) is a bad idea? I assume that would exacerbate the hydrolysis of the sugar.
Can I double or triple the citric acid without changing the flavor (beyond making it more sour)?
Is adding some ascorbic acid a good idea?
Would adding the flavoring before cooking be a bad idea? Would the heat decompose it, evaporate it, or something else?
Is it feasible to use lemon zest instead of extract? If I made lemon sugar, either by putting sugar and zest slices in a jar, or by blending zest and sugar together, will that work, or will heating it degrade the flavor?


There are a lot of questions here, which doesn't really fit the SE format - you might want to consider breaking it up into a couple of separate questions - one about the citric/ascorbic acids, and the other about the flavourings.

I wondered if the citric acid might break down/decompose around 300 °F, but according to Wikipedia, that doesn't happen until 350 °F.

The tartaric acid (what cream of tartar is) has a similar effect on the sugar chemistry to citric acid - indeed, either can be used as the acid catalyst for sucrose -> fructose+glucose, so I don't follow your logic.
